# View the incremental number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to view another column to the below table that presents the incremental number of row, I have tried to use `ROW_NUMBER()` but don't know how this function would work with my query

```
+---+--------------+
| c | POLICYNUMBER |
+---+--------------+
| 4 | 13080741     |
| 1 | 13600033     |
| 1 | 13600034     |
| 2 | 14001875     |
| 2 | 2393681      |
| 1 | J9023297     |
| 1 | J9023298     |
| 1 | J9023299     |
| 1 | J9023607     |
+---+--------------+
```

The query that I am using is as the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) AS c, fdp.POLICYNUMBER
FROM PICustomerService p
JOIN CFChangeFolder c ON (c.CASEFOLDERID = SUBSTRING(p.RK_PI_TO_CFCHANGE,9,LEN(p.RK_PI_TO_CFCHANGE))) 
JOIN FDPolicyDetails fdP ON c.CASEFOLDERID = fdP.PARENT_CASEID 
INNER JOIN SONORAHISTORYW sw (nolock) ON p.WFWORKITEMID = sw.ID  
WHERE sw.info = 'PriorWorkstepName=ProcessingWorkstepName=UnderwritingProcessing'
AND CONVERT(DATE,p.WFFLOWENTRYTIME) BETWEEN CONVERT(date,'20200716') AND CONVERT(DATE,'20200730')
AND CONVERT(DATE,sw.MODIFIEDDATETIME) >= CONVERT(DATE,'20200716') 
GROUP BY fdp.POLICYNUMBER
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` on top of your main query:

```
SELECT a.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c) AS incremental_rowid
FROM (
    SELECT distinct count(*) as c, fdp.POLICYNUMBER
    FROM PICustomerService p
    JOIN CFChangeFolder c ON (c.CASEFOLDERID = SUBSTRING(p.RK_PI_TO_CFCHANGE,9,LEN(p.RK_PI_TO_CFCHANGE))) 
    JOIN FDPolicyDetails fdP ON c.CASEFOLDERID = fdP.PARENT_CASEID 
    INNER JOIN SONORAHISTORYW sw (nolock) ON p.WFWORKITEMID = sw.ID      
    WHERE sw.info = 'PriorWorkstepName=ProcessingWorkstepName=UnderwritingProcessing'
    AND CONVERT(DATE,p.WFFLOWENTRYTIME) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE,'20200716') and CONVERT(DATE,'20200730')
    AND CONVERT(DATE,sw.MODIFIEDDATETIME) >= CONVERT(DATE,'20200716') 
    GROUP BY fdp.POLICYNUMBER
) a ORDER BY incremental_rowid;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: No need for nesting, you can simply write `select row_number() over(order by count(*)), count(*)...`